# Assigning value to struct's field, change also other variable

Tags: c++

Simple code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int bar;
};
struct foo tab[2];

int sum = 0;

int main()
{
    tab[2].bar = 3; //this change 'sum' value!
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result in 3 instead of 0. It is unbelievable, so problably I am missing something. What I have done wrong?

Comment: array access out of bounds. see [here](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays start at 0, so tab[2] would be the third element, but you only allocated 2 of them.

In this case, sum is in the memory directly after tab, so when you go to where the third tab would be, you're actually in the memory for sum.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you access `tab[2]` which is an overflow (its size is 2 so valid indices are 0 and 1).
So `tab[2]` accesses the memory address of `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your variable

```
struct foo tab[2];
```

`tab[2]` does not exist. 
You can only do

```
tab[0].bar = 3

tab[1].bar = 3
```

because arrays index starts from **0** and ends at `arraySize-1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely tab has a length of 2. By accessing the index 2, you are accessing memory out of the tab, which means you are accessing sum.

This is the reason why you are changing sum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, turn on compiler warnings! If you'd allow the compiler to help you, then it would very likely point out the exact error in this line:

> ```
> tab[2].bar = 3; //this change 'sum' value!
> ```

Depending on which compiler you use, the warning may be as follows:

```
warning: array subscript is above array bounds
```

`struct foo tab[2];` has two elements with indices 0 and 1, you try access a non-existing 3rd element. This results in **undefined behaviour** of your program. Whatever results you got, it was just random. Your program could also randomly crash.

---

Note that your code is also half C and half C++. That's not good. You don't need to write `struct foo` when you want to refer to the `foo` type, it's enough to write `foo`. Instead of a raw array, `std::array<Foo, 2>` can be used. And `using namespace std;` should not be used by default.